# Libreoffice PPA 4.1.x for latest Ubuntu version

Tags: libreoffice, ppa

I am looking for a PPA that has LibreOffice 4.1. Even though it is in Beta I wish to test it out via a PPA. So is there a PPA that has the LibreOffice 4.1.x branch?