# Best office suite supporting Hebrew for Ubuntu

Tags: language-support, microsoft-office

I've recently installed Ubuntu and I'm looking for a word processor that supports Hebrew (wine simply doesn't support Hebrew) and may replace MS word. I'm really new to the system, so it would be perfect if somebody would recommend a suite and how can I install it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I use Libreoffice Suite.

Make sure that the Hebrew keyboard layout is added.

[image]

If you don't have Libreoffice installed, the you can installed it, by looking at this [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303349/libreoffice-ppa-4-1-x-for-latest-ubuntu-version/303475#303475).

Open Libreoffice Writer, and click on tools --> Options

[image]

Then make the changes shown in the image below.  Once done click OK.  You may want to download and install the [Open Source Unicode Hebrew Font Pack](http://opensiddur.org/2010/07/unicode-compliant-and-open-source-licensed-hebrew-fonts/).

כאן אתה הולך .

[image]

Click on Right-To-Left, and start typing.

[image]

Comment: then I'll have fonts like David and will be able to write RTL text?

Comment: See addition in the answer.

Comment: About the fonts: Are there any other less-biblic fonts (e.g in office there were arial,david,david-transperent etc...)?

Comment: I honestly don't know, since I don't use Hebrew.  But take a look [Here](http://www.fontspace.com/category/hebrew).

Comment: O.k thanks. I've already found my desired ttf file :)