# How to type Hebrew?

Tags: 20.04

How can I make my comp type Hebrew in Ubuntu 20.04?   I don't know where to  begin, I'm a bit of a luddite when it comes to computers.

Comment: I know nothing about Hebrew but this answer seems to cover it. You appear to need to install Hebrew fonts and enable the Hebrew keyboard https://askubuntu.com/questions/339628/best-office-suite-supporting-hebrew-for-ubuntu/339644#339644

Comment: That answer there says I must go to LibreOffice, and then to tools - options - keyboard lay out, but I cannot find there any keyboard layout.